# Predict with survreg/tobit goes past bound

Tags: r, prediction, predict, survival-analysis

So I am using survreg, and I expect my predicted results to obey a lower bound of 0, but they indicate negative results frequently. I think it is somehow estimating a linear result instead of the survival model I'm trying to create. Here's what I've done:

```
linear.first.stage<-lm(y ~ x, data=clip)
```

First I estimated some points to speed up my estimation process. It fails to converge without this first stage. I create a survival object, following the code from ?survreg that provides an explicit example of a tobit regression. I duplicated this below for x and y. In my data set, y can only be observed at a non-negative value, but if it is positive, it tends to be distributed normally around 200 or so with sd of about 20.  X may take any value and isn't theoretically bound by any particular number that immediately comes to mind.

```
surv_y<-Surv(clip$y, clip$y>0,type="left")
first.stage<-survreg(surv_y ~ x,init=(linear.first.stage), dist="gaussian", data=clip)
```

I run the survival regression, which should be equivalent to a Tobit. To confirm that my interpretation of events were the same, I ran the following:

```
test<-tobit(y~x, left=0, right=Inf, dist="gaussian", data=clip)
p_test<-predict(test)
p<-predict(first.stage)
plot(p_test-p)
```

The plot shows a flat line at zero, so upon visual inspection these commands are identical, as they should be. However, in both cases, results under 0 are predicted. This is problematic because I have stated that the leftward bound of observable information is 0.  My expectations is that all predicted values must be >0.

I have tried predicting using types "link", "response", "linear", but to no avail. I assume the predict command is producing the outcomes *as if the censorship was not occurring*.  How do I produce the prediction that obeys the lower bound of 0?

References:

1. [Running predict() after tobit() in package AER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777088/running-predict-after-tobit-in-package-aer)
2. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11440/standardized-residuals-of-a-tobit-model-in-r

Comment: Can you explain the construction of the `Surv` object? The `event` is defined by `clip$y >0`. So why wouldn't force some of the predictions to be negative? (I don't really understand how this construction makes sense, either. Defining the event on the basis of the time of observation just seems wrong. Generally one needs to that the survival and censoring process to be more independent than this.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment about the time of the observation- I'm only familiar with the Tobit usage of this regression.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding the application of surreg?  I've tried to clarify above.

Comment: I've ran the same thing using the canned Tobit command, so at a minimum I am not confused as to how the command's syntax is operating here. Y is not a duration in this case. Instead, y is something like wages (which cannot drop below 0), and x is something like education levels, which is a factor of employment/wages.

Comment: If you change the dist type to "gaussian" you should expect the 'response' and 'linear predictor' to be the same. You are doing estimation in your case on a truncated dataset, which is conceptually a bit different than a censored dataset, so our terminology is probably not shared. Communication might be improved if you offered code to simulate your data situation. I know 'survreg' is in the survial package but I am only guessing that the 'tobit' function you have used is in the AER package.

Comment: That answers my question:  Tobit is the wrong regression type to use here, ergo, my funny results.  Thank you.

Comment: You should probably answer your own question (and not leave the resolution as a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Tobit is not the right regression type. Tobit predicts what the result ought to be in the absence of the truncation.

Clarification: I restructured my estimation process to reflect a zero-inflated or hurdle model. Tobit is for censored data, it says there exists a non-zero result, but we only observe 0 because the information is hidden somehow. For example, women's wages should be fit with Tobit, because married women who choose not to work still have a reservation wage, and still have some (invisible) return to effort doing unpaid labor of whatever type. Zero-inflated or hurdle models indicate that the result is truly zero. As in, no crimes occurred. Or no widgets produced. They more accurately reflected my model.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer? If Tobit predicts what ought to be in absence of truncation (did not know that...), what should be used to predict with the truncation? Thanks!

Comment: I restructured my estimation process to reflect a zero-inflated or hurdle model. 

Tobit is for censored data, it says there exists a non-zero result,  but we only observe 0 because the information is hidden somehow.  For example, women's wages should be fit with Tobit, because married women who choose not to work still have a reservation wage, and still have some (invisible) return to effort doing unpaid labor of whatever type.

Zero-inflated or hurdle models indicate that the result is truly zero. As in, no crimes occurred. Or no widgets produced. They more accurately reflected my model.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to scale the prediction up in the sense that is described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149091/censored-regression-in-r) by one of the authors of the package.